# Change default text in the popup appearing after installation

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Right after installation there is opening a popup with a default text like `Extension has been added to Chrome. Use this extension by clicking on this icon...`.

[image]

Ho can i change this text to my own text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default behavior after install using the `chrome.runtime.onInstall` and `OnInstalledReason` from here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime. You can set a new custom page as in a welcome message or instructions to use your extension.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (object) {
    if (chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL === object.reason) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL("welcome.html")}, function (tab) {
            console.log("New tab launched with instructions to use the extension");
        });
    }
});
```

this is on `background.js` and will be triggered when installed. Using this way you can set even an update event so you can inform the users about the new changes on your extension.

Comment: Should `welcome.html` be added anyhow to `manifest.json`? Is it `default_popup`?

Comment: Yes, should be added in manifest under `web_accessible_resources` as stated here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources

Comment: I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in the line `chrome.tabs.create(url:chrome.extension.getURL("welcome.html")}, function (tab) {`

Comment: Please add { before 'url: ..'